# How to enter data into ASPX controls programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, forms, http

At work I am being tasked with writing a tool that continually tries to login to our webpage.

I was specifically told not to do it using our webservice, but to actually fill in the page as a user would.

The page is an ASPX page and the controls are all run server side. The submit button calls a server side method and is not as simple as:

> www.website.com/login.aspx?username=x&password=x.

or

```
POST: www.website.com/login.aspx
<login>
    <username>x</username>
    <password>x</password
</login>
```

The idea I had was to use the web browser control built into WinForms, but that just doesn't seem like the best way?

How should I go about this?

NOTE: This is our website so this doesn't need to be generic and I can hardcode the names of the form controls.

```
public bool Login(string url, string username, string password)
{
}
```

Comment: `password` in QueryString is so sweet.

Comment: If its just calling a website with username and password insecurely in the query string just do an [http get](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307023)

Comment: Its not, the textboxes and the button are server side, Its not that simple

Comment: My mistake, I didnt see the not.

Comment: If its automated tests you want to make, you should look into [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Ive actually done just this 2 days ago using a command line tool.

I used code taken from .net test automation recipes so I cant post it here, but you basically create a webclient, then send requests pretending to be from a web browser.

Infact the system.net webclient class has a good [sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also look at the [HttpWebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which could help

If you want to send things via the post method cast your webrequest to a httwebrequest like this

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.method = "POST"
```

If its you need to pass in the viewstate too which is a pain. this should get you started.

Comment: Doesnt look like this is what the OP is looking for.  No post or URL params to get the data into the page.  Must stuff the username and password into the fields in the page then click.